# Getting SVN check in date and comment in one line

Tags: svn

```
svn log -l1
```

returns:

```
r82357 | Billy Murphy | 2019-01-27 11:24:40 +0000 (Fri, 25 Jan 2019) | 1 line

API-41: Added new method in existing class for validation
```

I don't care about the author. Only the date and the comment.  Is there any way I can get that one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following PowerShell snippet:

```
$x = [xml](svn log https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk -l 3 --xml)

$x.log.logentry | Format-List -Property @{n='Date'; e={($_.Date)}}, @{n='Log message'; e={($_.msg)}}
```

It prints the log message and a date of the latest 3 commits. Here is an example:

```
Date        : 2019-01-31T21:28:04.122821Z
Log message : * subversion/libsvn_client/wc_editor.c
                (svn_client__wc_copy_mods): Remove the WC locking, now that the
                  WC editor does it, following r1852559.

Date        : 2019-01-31T19:36:52.166250Z
Log message : Comment out a failing swig-rb test.

              Issue 4805, "delta path editor binding broken for root path".

              * subversion/bindings/swig/ruby/test/test_delta.rb
                (test_path_driver): Comment out (as no XFail mechanism is available).

Date        : 2019-01-31T16:51:48.130607Z
Log message : Improve backward compatibility for svn_delta_path_driver2().

              This ensures the input array is not modified, and changes the behaviour to
              be less surprising.

              * subversion/include/svn_delta.h,
                subversion/libsvn_delta/deprecated.c
                (svn_delta_path_driver2): Add back slash prefixes if any, rather than the
                  first, of the inputs had one. Duplicate the array if modifying it.
```

You can also replace the `Format-List` cmdlet with `Select-Object` and the output will be different:

```
Date                        Log message                                                                                                              
----                        -----------                                                                                                              
2019-01-31T21:28:04.122821Z * subversion/libsvn_client/wc_editor.c...                                                                                
2019-01-31T19:36:52.166250Z Comment out a failing swig-rb test....                                                                                   
2019-01-31T16:51:48.130607Z Improve backward compatibility for svn_delta_path_driver2()....
```